# What are the differences between On-net calls and Off-net calls?

Tags: telecommunication

What are the differences between On-net calls and Off-net calls? 
How could I make international call under On-net call?

Comment: on-net calls are calls between the same network.off-net calls are calls with other networks.

Comment: could I make international call under On-net call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `'On-Net'` is used when your call or message originates on your home operator's network and terminates to another mobile number that resides with your operator. It does not matter if the person you are calling is using the home network or is off Island roaming with a different provider. `'Off-Net'` applies when the call or message is made on a different network, e.g. whilst you are roaming, or if you are using your home network and make a call or send a message to a number that resides with a different network provider

Comment: many thanks for helping. actually i am new in this area and i am working in the security issues in telecommunication (fraud)>

Comment: visit this how to mark accepted answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: many thanks for helping. actually i am new in this area and i am working in the security issues in telecommunication (fraud). I have this definitions but I am still confused could you please clarify to me. For an operator, if a fraudster uses its own network’s connections to terminate the bypassed 
calls, it is identied as ONNET Bypass Fraud
But  if  the  fraudster  uses  competitor’s  connections  or  any  other  means  for  termination,  it  is 
identied as OFFNET Bypass Fraud